# ERROR HANDLING and Loading into target Table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario Today where I am stucked Up little bit. I have data like this below in my Source Oracle Source Table(Sample Data)

```
ID,NAME,SALARY,BIRTHDAY
1,ABHIJIT,2000,17/12/1990
2,ROHIT,-2000,13/11/1988
3,MOHIT,500,2075-575-43
```

Now Salary in the 2nd Row is negetive and BIRTHDAY in the 3rd Row is an Invalid Format(Valid is MM/dd/yyyy). Both 2nd and 3rd Row should go to INVALID_EMPLOYEE and 1st record should go to VALID_EMPLOYEE. In the Source File Date Format is coming as dd/mm/yyyy. Which I have to convert to MM/dd/yyyy format and also have to check whether Date Format incoming in Source File is dd/mm/yyyy or not. Salary should not be less than 0. Source Table All columns are in String and in Target Table ID is Integer,NAME as VARCHAR2(255), SALARY is NUMBER and BIRTHDAY is DATE. 
I have handled all this in my Project ETL Tool. So I am trying to push all this in Query to improve performance.Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is your question "How to implement these validations using SQL query" ? If not, please describe your issue.

Comment: Hi @shrek,  Yes My Question is that. How to implement this validations using sql query as well as loading and converting to respective DataTypes. Because My Project ETL Tool is giving too bad Throughput

Comment: AnyOne any help

Comment: Why should first row go to `valid_employee` even though its birthday is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error records should be ideally handled by the process that's doing the insert, in many cases this may not be possible to do.
Instead what you can do now is to set up constraints on the table for the Salary column. The date checking can be implemented by simply having the column of the date datatype. Then create a error logging table to log the errors.

Now we need a table to log your invalid records. For this you have two options. 
You can have the `INVALID_EMPLOYEES` table itself as the error table. But that would mean having additional columns in the table (`ORA_ERR_MESG$` and `ORA_ERR_TAG$`).

If having additional columns is not an option then you can create a dedicated error table and then move the records from this table to your `INVALID_EMPLOYEES` table. You will have to write some code that runs after your insert code to move the records.

See the [DBMS_ERRLOG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_errlog.htm#ARPLS66320) package to see how to create the error logging tables.

Once you have your error logging tables created you have to instruct your [INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BCEGDJDJ) code to log the errors into your error logging table. This will ensure that all the valid records get inserted in your employees table and the invalid records go to your error table with a column that stores the error that was encountered while inserting that particular record. So your insert code would look something like

```
INSERT INTO VALID_EMPLOYEES
    SELECT ID,
             NAME,
             SALARY,
             BIRTHDAY
      FROM my_source_table
          LOG ERRORS INTO INVALID_EMPLOYEES ('Oops this guy failed');
```

In this case 'Oops this guy failed' would go into the `ORA_ERR_TAG$` column of the error table. You can use this tag column to identify different insert statements that tried to insert an invalid record.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Arijit,      yes we have Dedicated Error Table where All the DataType is String matching with my Source Table. If This is my Source Data ID,NAME,SALARY,BIRTHDAY
1,ABHIJIT,2000,17/12/1990
2,ROHIT,-2000,15/09/1988
3,MOHIT,500,2075-575-43
4,SHAUN,-700,15/10/1989 Then How I will write my Query to move 2nd and 4th Row to ERROR_TABLE which is negetive Salary and 3rd Row to ERROR TABLE AS That is also an Invalid Record for InValid Date

Comment: The errorlog table created by `DBMS_ERRLOG` package have all columns as VARCHAR2(4000). So you can either drop your existing error log table and recreate it using the DBMS_ERRLOG package or you can create a dedicated error log table and then move the records from that table to your error logging table. That will be a separate insert after your main insert.

Comment: Arijit, Soumitra, Can You atleast give an idea how to construct this sql with Negetive Value checkings?Date I will handle in my ETL in that case

Comment: @Abhijit, If I understand correctly, you need to process all the data from the source and load it into your Target table including invalid records also. So, you simply need a mechanism(SQL queries) to identify the invalid records and push them into a Error table? If my understanding is correct, I propose you should have a Flag column in your target table (eg: validation_flag) which will hold True/False values depending upon your validation results. Let me know if this is what you want? I'll suggest you SQL queries for your invalid cases later.

Comment: Hi @Mayank, Yes. But My actual Target Table dont have any flag. Maybe Any temp Table which will be having a flag to identify actual and invalid records. Yess. Can you guide for sql query

Comment: I think you should add a column "validation_flag" in your target table, because, if you use a temp table, you might truncate it on each run and you will lose history of invalid records for previous runs. Regarding SQL queries: when all data(valid and invalid) is loaded in your target table, run queries like: 
    update employees set validation_flag='FALSE'
    where salary<0;update employees set validation_flag='FALSE'
    where to_char(Birthday, 'YYYY') > to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
Above will identify invalid records in your tgt table.Now move them in  error table using Insert.

Comment: @Abhijit, The check for negative values can be implemented using a constraint on the table column. You can add it to the table using `ALTER TABLE valid_employees
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_sal_non_neg CHECK (salary > 0);`